# How thread works in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I need some help as I have a piece of code int rails, that is to be executed in `email_open_order` action so that I can run the email task in the background and release the GUI.

```
def email_open_order  
  @order_list = OpenOrder.where(:user_id => current_user)
  t = Thread.new { invoke_webservice method: 'post', action: 'send_open_order', data: { custNo: current_user,custEm: session[:buyer_email], orders: @order_list} }

  at_exit { t.join }
end
```

`invoke_webservice` method calls the web service, i.e HTTP POST and sends email to group of users.

The normal time it takes to deliver all open order list is `87.12`

```
Benchmark.measure { invoke_webservice method: 'post', action: 'send_open_order', data: { custNo: current_user,custEm: session[:buyer_email], orders: @order_list} }
=> 0.010000 0.000000 0.010000 ( 87.124463)
```

as soon as I create a new thread and pass the `invoke_webservice` method to thread block it starts sending mail and GUI is released.

I wonder what happens to the thread when the execution of the code block gets completed/fails.

Does the thread terminates or remains in sleep mode?

How does this thread work? Does it create a new PID?

I use Unicorn as my web Server.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not create a new PID (since that would imply a new process rather than a new thread). When the thread has done your work it will terminate.

Typically rails apps do this by using something like delayed_job, sidekiq etc. to process these jobs in a separate process rather than by creating threads within the app - it's often uncertain how long the web server process will survive after the request is finished (passenger starts/kills application processes based on load) and you don't get much visibility into the status of these threads.

Answer (score 0):

I get you , But will the thread cause any issue once it is terminated.
I have a application where I need to send mail and I don't want to use any background jobs.

The thread I create takes only 7 seconds to process and terminate , Do I need to destroy the thread object like:

```
thread = Thread.new { 4+7 }
thread.destroy
```