# Avoiding email delivery delays with Rails Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, actionmailer

The Users Controller in my Rails app delivers an email in its creation action after @user has been saved as below:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        UserMailer.welcome_notification(@user).deliver
        format.js { }
      else
        # more code
      end
   end
```

The action simply sends a Welcome email to a user that has just signed up.
Everything works fine but delivering the email is taking around two seconds which translates in two seconds the user has to wait after clicking the submit button in the sign-up form. This delay is rather awkward and I'm considering mitigating it with either:

1. Use a 'loading...' animation (I'm not fond of doing this since the
   delay will still be there.
2. Sending the email as a background job with a gem such as [Delayed-job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

I'm inclined to the second option but since I haven't done this before I worry about:

1. Is this an overkill? I'll be just sending this email. Wonder if 
   this is not too much.
2. A potential increase in Heroku's costs due to a wrong config of workers or just the use of them.
3. Although I've done some research, I'm still unclear on which of those gems would suit this problem best.

Could you advise on the best practices to reduce delays of this kind?

Comment: If you upgrade to Rails 5 you get the Async adapter - https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/29/rails-5-changed-default-active-job-adapter-to-async.html

Comment: It's not overkill, it's normal practice to queue long tasks through Sidekiq for example. If it's not critical just do it (in my case user upload images and needs to see result, so I don't use it for this case, but I plan to do for mailings). I think Sidekiq is acknowledged as one of the most versatile.

Comment: You can also encapsulate your mailing task into a thread `Thread.new` like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245296/how-thread-works-in-ruby-on-rails but be careful, as it is not queued, if you have more than 5 concurrent threads, Puma (or the Database server) may just crash your app (you dont have to restart server but the tasks wont be performed)